# QGIS Processing algorithms have encoding problems

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, encoding

I use QGIS 2.14.1.

I add vector layer from UTF-8 encoded geojson, which is read fine and attribute table show correct characters.

If I use QGIS algorithm on this layer (i.e. clip, voronoi, etc) I get new layer which attribute table is full of question marks instead correct characters.

If I use SAGA algorithm (i.e. clip) characters in newly created layer are fine.

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Which algorithm do you use ? from FTools or from Processing ? in some other words, which menu are you using in QGIS (vector or Processing) ?

Comment: I use Processing toolbox to run algorithms

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I see now what you mean. Running algorithms from menu makes correctly encoded layers

Comment: Hum, FTools will be removed from QGIS 2.16 and Processing will replace these algorithms. This bug should be fixed.

Comment: If that's so, hopefully someone reported this bug as their issue tracker is unavailable right now: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: The issue tracker is working now. You should include more informations like OS, geojson file in your ticket.

Comment: Done, http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14704